Delphi: VirtualKeyboard events not reliably triggered with Android Gesture Navigation
I’m encountering an issue in a Delphi app when using Android's Gesture Navigation feature. Specifically, the VirtualKeyboard hide and show events are only triggered every second attempt when performing a hardware back (HwBack) gesture. This problem does not occur when using the 3-button navigation system.
Here’s a video explaining Android Gesture Navigation for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ljtz7T8R_Hk
Reproduction steps:

Create a TForm in Delphi.
Add a component (e.g., an TEdit) that triggers the VirtualKeyboard.
Use Android Gesture Navigation and attempt to hide the keyboard using the HwBack gesture.
Observe that the VirtualKeyboard hide event is triggered only on every second attempt.

Additional context:

When using the 3-button navigation system, the events are triggered
reliably.
Related issue reports: RSP-2040 and RSP-2047 (submitted to
Embarcadero).

Has anyone encountered similar issues, and if so, is there a known workaround or fix?
The issue occurs in Delphi version 12.2 with the latest patches applied. However, I believe this behavior might be present in earlier versions as well—likely those supporting Android 10, which introduced Gesture Navigation support.
Edit: Some additional insights on this. There is a difference between using the back gesture (swiping from the left or right edge to the center) and using the small button below the keyboard to hide it. When using the small keyboard button, the behavior can be consistently reproduced.

For reference, the video you linked to does not give any useful information about the change in behaviour of the Virtual Keyboard when Gesture Navigation is enabled. I confirm that the OnVirtualKeyboardHidden event is not called when this feature is turned on. I expect that EMBT will need to fix this within the Java code that Delphi uses (part of the fmx.jar library)

You have also already asked this question a month ago, here. Doing this on SO is poor form

Thank you for pointing that out. I lost track of the number of bugs I had to deal with over the past six months. I voted to close the other question as a duplicate because this one describes the problem more accurately and omits unnecessary information. Feel free to do the same. We have a timeschedule for our company APP so I feel a little preasure on that and beacuse I get no Feedback from EMBT after a Month I started grasping at straws. Sorry for the inconvenience.

For what it's worth: I did a bit of investigating into this issue and was unable to find a viable solution, even in Java. When Gesture Navigation is enabled, it appears impossible to determine when the VK is hidden, as the "visible" area of the screen is the same as the whole area, which is just nuts (since the VK covers part of it). I'm happy to be proven wrong, though :-)

I'm afraid you are completely right. Any idea on how to get EMBT's attention on this?

@DaveNottage Why would "visible" area be any smaller when VK is shown? In FireMonkey VK is rendered over the surface of the given AControl and this us part of your application.

As far as I know the VK is automatically shown the caret is visible and then hidden when the caret is no longer visible. So it is possible that using back button and Gesture Navigation provides different behavior on the OS level. I don't have the latest Android device at hand in order to do some testing, but does perhaps Navigation Gesture on first swipe reverts last change made in edit field similar as pressing ESC key would on PC and only on the second swipe performs back navigation?

@SilverWarior Good point, but that's not the case. Pressing VkBack on a focused edit will remove the focus from that edit. Let's not bring up tMemo in this context. There seems to be a bug with the focus and VkBack as well.


Why would "visible" area be any smaller when VK is shown?
Because the VK obscures part of the application UI. When Gesture Navigation is not enabled, it correctly reports the size of the visible area

